# PHP AJAX JSON checking if data is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Currently, my code below is sending a partner-code to a PHP script and returning JSON data.

```
 $('a.pComment').on('click', function()
 {
   var partnercode = $(this).attr('data-code');
   if($.trim(partnercode) != '')
   {
     $.post('api/searchPComment.php', {partnercode: partnercode}, function(data)
     {
       var obj = JSON.parse(data);
       $('#pCodeComment').empty();
       $.each(obj, function(index, item)
       {
           $('<li>').
           text(item.datestamp+' - '+item.comment).
           appendTo($('#pCodeComment'));
       });
     })
   }
 });
```

The above code works. I am able to query the database and return data into a modal window.

The problem is, if a partner-code has no comment, the modal need to return no comment.  Currently, if you click a link that has a comment, then click on a link that has no comment, the link that has no comment will display the previous comment.

I need to clear out the last comment, or run a check to see if the partner-code being sent has no comment and return just a screen that says, "No comment."

I am still new to AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should fix your server side code and verify you're returning a valid json object when there are no comments. Right now you've only defined a success callback on $.post so if there's an error on return, nothing will happen (so the comment from the last click event is still in there).

You can also fix the issue without modifying the server side code by also including a fail callback (Note: if there's a network timeout or similar it will run the fail function as well)

```
 $.post('api/searchPComment.php', {partnercode: partnercode}, function(data)
 {
  // this is called on success only
  // ..rest of your code
 }.fail( function(){
   $('#pCodeComment').html( 'No Comment' );
 });
```

Comment: I took your advice and fixed the issue in the php script. Thank you.